# Saving float to a text file is not working correctly

Tags: c#, xna

I use the following code to display the elapsed time on the screen. Displaying time works correctly. But saving the time sometimes doesn’t work correctly, for example if Time = 2,000001

Before Saving, the displayed time is 0:02.000

After saving and loading the string from the text file the displayed time is 0:02.100

I found out, that there is something wrong in this line, because str1 = 2 and str2 = 1 and therefore newline = 2,1 instead of 2,000001

```
newline = str1.ToString() + "," + str2.ToString();
```

What is wrong with my code? What should I change so that the time gets written correctly in a text file?

```
string s1;

float Time, delta;

delta = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds; 

Time += delta;

TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Time);

s1 = ts.ToString("m\\:ss\\.fff");
```

After the level is completed, I save the time in a text file like this:

```
int str1, str2;

string[] strs1;

string line = Time;

strs1 = line.Split(',');

str1 = int.Parse(strs1[0]);

str2 = int.Parse(strs1[1]);

newline = str1.ToString() + "," + str2.ToString();
```

Writing the string in a text file:

```
stream.WriteLine(newline);
```

Loading the string from the text file:

```
private static System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");

string line = reader.ReadLine();

strs = line.Split(';');   

float YourTime = float.Parse(strs[0], culture);
```

Comment: It *looks* like the question here is actually : "the integer `str2` has value `1`, but I want it to write as `000001` - how do I do that?" - is that right? note: when you parse a string as an integer, any formatting is lost - once you've parsed `"000001"`, it is just the integer `1` - nothing more.

Comment: um, you write thing,otherthing on the way out and try to split by ; on the way back?

Comment: `string newline = $"{str1},{str2.Trim('-').PadLeft(6, '0')}";`

Comment: @ Marc Gravell Yes, I don't want to loose the "000001", because after loading the string from the text file the time is 0:02.100 instead of 0:02.000.

Comment: zeroes after a decimal point are significant. you can't afford to lose them when you convert to string and back. why not just save `s1` to the file? or convert into a number of ticks, then you can deal with an (integer) long, and will have no culture dot-or-comma issues.